# How to allocate a structure with arrays in one chunk in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am building a neural network, and for optimization purposes, I need it to allocate the entire neuron network in one chunk. Here it is...

```c
typedef struct NetworkType {
    int in_count;
    int hidden_count;
    int hidden_layers_count;
    int out_count;
    int size;

    float *input;
    float *output;
    float *hidden;
    float *bias;
    float *weight;
    float *delta;
} Network;
```

And here is its initialization.

```c
Network *init_network(int in_count, int hidden_layers_count, int hidden_count, int out_count) {
    if (hidden_layers_count < 0) return NULL;
    if (in_count < 1) return NULL;
    if (out_count < 1) return NULL;
    if (hidden_layers_count > 0 && hidden_count < 1) return NULL;

    int hidden_weights = 0;
    if (hidden_layers_count > 0) {
        hidden_weights = in_count * hidden_count + (hidden_layers_count - 1) * hidden_count * hidden_count;
    }

    int output_weights = in_count * out_count;
    if (hidden_layers_count > 0) {
        output_weights = hidden_count * out_count;
    }

    int total_weights = hidden_weights + output_weights;
    int total_neurons = in_count + hidden_count * hidden_layers_count + out_count;
    int total_bias = total_neurons - in_count;
    int total_deltas = total_neurons - in_count;

    /* Allocate extra size for weights, neurons, bias and deltas... */
    int size = sizeof(Network) + sizeof(float) * (total_weights + total_neurons + total_bias + total_deltas);
    Network *net = (Network *)malloc(size);
    if (!net) return NULL;

    net->in_count = in_count;
    net->hidden_count = hidden_count;
    net->hidden_layers_count = hidden_layers_count;
    net->out_count = out_count;
    net->size = size;

    /* Set pointers. */
    float* start_data_address = (float *)((char *)net + sizeof(Network));
    net->input = start_data_address;
    net->output = net->input + in_count;
    net->hidden = net->output + out_count;
    net->bias = net->hidden + hidden_count;
    net->weight = net->bias + total_bias;
    net->delta = net->weight + total_weights;

    srand(time(NULL));
    randomize(net->bias, total_bias);
    randomize(net->weight, total_weights);

    return net;
}

void randomize(float *arr, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        /* Sets value from -0.5 to 0.5. */
        arr[i] = GET_RANDOM() - 0.5;
    }
}
```

But for some reason, I get this output from Valgrind. In total 2712 errors from 10 contexts. Have you any idea why Valgrind is so mad at me.

```
==2719== Invalid write of size 4
==2719==    at 0x110094: randomize(float*, int) (helpers.cpp:41)
==2719==    by 0x1102CD: init_network(int, int, int, int) (neuron.cpp:54)
==2719==    by 0x10FB63: main (main.cpp:18)
==2719==  Address 0x4bd047c is 60 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,189,088 in arena "client"
```

Comment: You might be able to create a solution with a Flexible Array Member.

Comment: Do-able, but a proper size calculation needs to account for padding.  Easiest to code with an added FAM `float[]` at the end.

Comment: `float* start_data_address = (float *)((char *)net + sizeof(Network));` <<-- this is basically just `(float*) (net+1)`

Comment: Hints: 1) use unsigned types (preferrably `size_t`) for sizes and counts. 2) reduce the number of casts in the code. (most of them can be avoided)

Comment: what were the arguments of `init_network(...)` that triggered this issue?

Comment: @tstanisl I used it like this `Network *net = init_network(4, 0, 50, 3);` and there is the issue, though hidden layers is 0 and I don't allocate memory for it, I still do shift here `net->bias = net->hidden + hidden_count;`. One extra if solved my problem.

Comment: Update: I neede to calculate the pointer using this formula `net->bias = net->hidden + hidden_count * hidden_layers_count;`

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to add a flexible member at the end of the struct. It will simplify code later on. Moreover, it will guarantee that the `float` data will be always correctly aligned.

```
typedef struct NetworkType {
  ...
  float data_[];
}
```

The suffix `_` is used to highlight that `data_` is a private member.

2. Try to delegate tracing an offset where the specific subarray starts to the compiler:

```
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t input_offset  = offset; offset += in_count;
    size_t output_offset = offset; offset += out_count;
    size_t hidden_offset = offset; offset += hidden_count;
    size_t bias_offset   = offset; offset += total_bias;
    size_t weight_offset = offset; offset += total_weights;
    size_t delta_offset  = offset; offset += total_deltas;
```

3. Using a flexible member vastly simplifies the allocation code.

```
Network *net = malloc(sizeof *net + offset * sizeof net->data_[0]);
```

4. After successful allocation set the internal pointer using the `*_offset` variables.

```
    net->size = offset;
 
     /* Set pointers. */
    net->input  = net->data_ + input_offset;
    net->output = net->data_ + output_offset;
    net->hidden = net->data_ + hidden_offset;
    net->bias   = net->data_ + bias_offset;
    net->weight = net->data_ + weight_offset;
    net->delta  = net->data_ + delta_offset;
```

After above changes the issue disappeared.